# nested <xsl:if> & <xsl:when>

Tags: xml, xslt

Can you nest xsl:if within nested xsl:when, for example:

```
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="param/@id  =  '1' " >
            <xsl:if test="param/value = 'XML' ">
                <xsl:when test="param/@id = '2' ">
                    <xsl:if test="param/value = 'HTTP' ">
                        <xsl:when test="param/@id = '3' ">
                            <xsl:if test="param/value = 'Y' ">
                                <xsl:call-template name="buildPayload"/>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
```

Can this be used, or is there away to streamline this into a more compact code?

Comment: Using xsl for complex logics...usually will lead to problems. :-)

Comment: How do you expect this to work?  If `param/@id = '1'` is true then `param/@id = '2'`... will be false;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without trying it: I'd think that `<xsl:when>` cannot be a child node of `<xsl:if>` without another `<xsl:choose>` in between. But, what are you trying to do? If I see that right, you want to run `<call-template>` if and only if `(param/@id='1' and param/value='XML') or (param/@id='2' and param/value='HTTP') or (param/@id='3' and param/value='Y')` ... try that as the test value:

```
<xsl:if test="(param/@id='1' and param/value='XML') or (param/@id='2' and param/value='HTTP') or (param/@id='3' and param/value='Y')">
    <xsl:call-template name="buildPayload"/>
</xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah this looks like it will not work.  You could add "and"s and "or"s in the **test** for the when.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read up on [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp).  You should be able to use XPath Expressions and the Node Selection syntax to help with this selection.

You may also try to use a visual XSLT designer such as the tooling in Visual Studio.  Visual Studio, for example, will provide IntelliSense and validation for XSLT.